# C# override an abstract method of generic type

Tags: c#, generics, methods, overriding, abstract

I did quite a bit of searching, I thought I got the pattern right but it's still not compiling, I would really appreciate a hand...

I have a generic class:

> ```
> public abstract class CTopology<TTopology>
> {
>     protected abstract TTopology Pcalc();
>     public TTopology PLosses()
>     { do something
>       return this.PCalc()
>     }
> ```

and then a derived class

```
   public class CInverter : CTopology<CPBoost>
    { 
     protected override CPInv PCalc()
        {
         CPInv Calc = new CPInv();
         do something
         return Calc;
        }
     }
```

Now I get these 2 compile errors:

Error   1   'iSine46.CInverter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'iSine46.CTopology.Pcalc()'

Error   2   'iSine46.CInverter.PCalc()': no suitable method found to override

Comment: Visual Studio has an intellisense feature that helps with this.  In the derived class, type "override PCalc" and hit enter.  Visual Studio will put in the  correct method or property with the right modifiers.

Answer (score 4):

Your override-method does not have the same result-type as provided by your base-class. You need to return a CPBoost-instance:

```
public class CInverter : CTopology<CPBoost> { 
    protected override CPBoost PCalc() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error is that you should preserve *method's signature*:

```
public abstract class CTopology<TTopology> {
  // Returns TTopology
  protected abstract TTopology Pcalc();
  ...
}

public class CInverter : CTopology<CPBoost> { 
  // Should also return TTopology, that is CPBoost in the case and not CPInv!
  protected override CPBoost PCalc() {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I had tried that but I get this error instead:
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'TTopology' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class CTopology<TTopology>
{
  protected abstract TTopology Pcalc();
}


public class CInverter : CTopology<CPBoost>
{ 
  // note that the return type is of the type you chose for TTopology
  // and the capitalization is correct
  protected override CPBoost Pcalc() 
  {
     return something;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CInverter : CTopology<CPBoost> { 
// You should return TTopology instead of CPInv
    protected override CPBoost PCalc() {
    ....
    }

}
```